# Regular Expression on XSD schema not validating string

Tags: regex, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate a string such as "1.9.29". Something like a version number in a software. The expression below wont work:

```
<xs:attribute name="version" use="required">
   <xs:simpleType>
      <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
         <xs:pattern value="[0-999]\.[0-999]\.[0-999]"/>
      </xs:restriction>
   </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

I also tried `\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\`
with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<xs:pattern value="[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"/>
```

`[0-999]` matches any one character in the following set: `0-9`, `9`, `9`. In other words, this is the same as doing `[0-9]`.

Note: You should also be able to replace `[0-9]` with `\d`..I believe the reason it didn't work in your second try was because of the trailing `\`.